# Neo4j cypher not filtering on label

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have some behaviour in Neo4j that confuses me.  I have a small embedded network that was created with Java.  The following cypher queries illustrate the problem.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n) return n._id,labels(n);
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| n._id                                                                        | labels(n)                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "/Users/simonshapiro/NetBeansProjects/XMLTest/src/xmltest/media/project.xml" | ["IdentityNode","Pedigree"] |
| <null>                                                                       | ["StateNode"]               |
| <null>                                                                       | ["StateNode"]               |
| "iqaS5pKAUBxk5wOW"                                                           | ["IdentityNode","MetaNode"] |
| <null>                                                                       | ["StateNode"]               |
| "2ahS5pKAUBxk5wOv"                                                           | ["IdentityNode","MetaNode"] |
| <null>                                                                       | ["StateNode"]               |
| "N3jS5pKAUBxk5wPJ"                                                           | ["IdentityNode","MetaNode"] |
| <null>                                                                       | ["StateNode"]               |
| "btoC1pKAUBxk5wQu"                                                           | ["IdentityNode","MetaNode"] |
| <null>                                                                       | ["StateNode"]               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But trying to filter on label as below returns no results.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:MetaNode) return n._id,labels(n);                  
+-------------------+
| n._id | labels(n) |
+-------------------+
+-------------------+
0 row
9 ms
```

Comment: It seems that 
`match (n) where "MetaNode" in labels(n) return n._id,labels(n)`
works.

Comment: What version of neo4j, I tested this with their [sample](http://console.neo4j.org/) and it worked fine. The query used was `match (n:Crew) return n._id, labels(n)`. Of course those nodes have no `_id` property but it fetched only those labeled `"Crew"`.

Comment: does `where n:MetaNode` work as well? Perhaps an issue with an older version where the index was broken? You can try to shutdown your db, make a backup and delete the `graph.db/schema` directory.

Comment: @Michael. where n:MetaNode does not work either.  The DB is deleted and recreated for each test run.  On the index it has an index using _id but based on the label 'IdentityNode'  The label 'MetaNode' is added by the user so I can't anticipate it and build an index for it.